# How to make a function wait until an ACK from a device is received via BLE using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’m trying to write a specific command to a device from my iPhone via BLE. For doing so, I have to send another command first which switches the current mode to the  COMMAND MODE, that is the mode to handle and interpret commands from my phone. After the COMMAND MODE has been set successfully, I will receive an ACK accordingly. I hope to resume sending my desired command after receiving the ACK. How to make my function wait until the ACK event takes place?

```
-(void) sendCommand(){

switchToCommandMode();

//How to achieve this:
//wait until ACK is received.
//

sendTheDesiredCommand();

}
```

Comment: Don't "wait".  Use a [state machine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you mind to give a little more explanation on how to use it in my case?

Comment: When programming for a modern interactive environment, like iOS, you need your code to be "event driven". When an event occurs you use the data for that event and the current state to decide what to do. You can use a variable to hold a value that represents the current state (an Enumeration works well). Your initial state is "start".  You send the command and set the state to "switch sent". When you get data back you check the state and confirm that the data is what you expected. If it is you move to the "command enabled" state and send the command, moving then to the "command sent" state Etc

Comment: If you don't get the right response at any time you can reset state to "error" or "retry" or whatever.  You can draw a state diagram to help you write the code.

Comment: This all means you can't really have a block `sendCommand` function. You might want to create a queue so that you can submit a command to be processed

Comment: Hi  Paulw11 , I’m with one question: every time I have to send a command, I need to set the current mode to COMMAND MODE first, and if the COMMAND MODE has been set properly, I always get a “SET SUCESSFULLY” ACK. However, I have more than one commands to be sent in my APP. Let’s say if I have command A,B, If I don’t wait in the function “sendCommadA()” and “sendCommandB()” respectively, how am I supposed to know it’s command A or command B that I have to send after receiving “SET SUCESSFULLY” ACK?

Comment: There are a few ways you could deal with that. As I said, I would probably use a queue and I would create an object to submit to the queue. Along with the require command, one of the properties of the object would be a block to invoke after the command has been executed. Your process is then to take the next item off the queue and "execute" it using the state machine. Once you get to a completed or error state you invoke the block from the current item passing the success/fail status or whatever. You then check the queue for more work to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the command to switch the status of the peripheral by writing a certain status value on a BLE characteristic in this way:

```
[peripheral writeValue:value forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

once the characteristic has been written, the didWriteValueForCharacteristic callback will be triggered and here you have the chance to send your desired command:

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{
if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:"STATUS_CHARACTERISTC"]]){
  //Status written: Write your command here  
}}
```

Remember to first set the CBPeripheralDelegate on your CBPeripheral object: the CBPeripheralDelegate object will be the one in which the didWriteValueForCharacteristic method will be implemented (e.g., it could be the viewController on which you are doing BLE operations but you can allocate a separate object also). Note that if you forget to set the CBPeripheralDelegate, the callback method will not be fired.

Another approach would be to first register your app to receive BLE notifications each time the status characteristic changes on the peripheral. In this way when you change the peripheral status (e.g., writing the BLE characteristic as described above), the CBPeripheralDelegate on the iOS app will be automatically notified and the didUpdateValueForCharacteristic callback will be fired in this case:

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{
if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:"STATUS_CHARACTERISTC"]]){

   NSData *dataValue = characteristic.value;
   NSString *stringValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSLog(@"Status changed in: %@", stringValue);

   //Send desired command here
}}
```

In order to activate notify value on a characteristic:

```
[peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:c];
```